# To put smb through to smb VS to pop smb through to smb

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Due to the nature of my work I have to make calls to our customers, and most of them are based in Australia and NZ. When talking to an operator, I'd quite often hear them say something along the lines of "I will pop you through to him/her". I have always thought the correct expression is "to put someone through to someone".

Is it just me not making out what they are saying? Or is this expression correct?

My gut feeling is saying "pop" is such a verb that you could use virtually in all situations that imply quick movement or gestures, hence I guess it might be used here in this context? I tried looking it up multiple times, but I haven't found any answers.

Cheers!

Comment: Let me ask you: If you hear it all the time, how can it be wrong? They mean to put someone through to someone. There is also the meaning of going to a place: pop round to my sister's house. Used in BrE.

Comment: I hear that in UK sometimes as "I'll just pop you on hold while I..." It sounds more friendly than 'putting' me on hold.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The reason I had doubts about this is mainly because there is literally nothing on the web on this. I did try googling it again before posting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Put you through” or “connect you to” are standard phrases in the U.S., but “pop you through” would be understood. There are many regional colloquialisms, and  I believe that Australia is not particularly deficient in them.